# Get (tell) AXScrollArea in Applescript (Or, classes not appearing)

Tags: applescript, accessibility

In my AppleScript I need to get the `AXScrollArea` on the left of Accessibility preferences. My first thought was to try using the `AXRoleDescription`, "scroll area", but it wouldn't compile.

> syntax error: Expected end of line but found identifier.

shows on the line with "scroll area". This appears to be a problem  with methods/classes not being imported in general as things like `click` show up as variables.

---

This is my code so far:

```
tell application "System Preferences" to run

tell application "System Events" to tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal (pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess")
    tell window 1
        tell scroll area 1

        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick fix:

Since System Preferences is the inner block, it disregards System Events "terms" (or keywords/classes/functions/routines etc.)

So you need to enclose it in this block:

```
using terms from application "System Events"
    -- code here
end using terms from
```

---

Although it's what I was technically asking, this isn't what I needed. I used `tell application` instead of `tell process` accidentally.

And here's the final script (I decided against the scroll area thing as anchors work better)

```
-- Toggles scrolling with the mouse
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    reveal anchor "Mouse" of (pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess")
    activate
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    tell window 1 of process "System Preferences"
        delay 0.1
        click button "Mouse Options…"
        click checkbox "Scrolling" of sheet 1
    end tell
    set visible of process "System Preferences" to false
end tell
```